# Copying Excel-Formula to different Workbook, without keeping reference

Tags: excel, vba

In Workbook1 I have the following formula in Cell AG9 in Worksheet "New Table1"

`=COUNTIF('New Table2'!B:B;"D")`

It's supposed to count all the D's in "New Table2" Column B.
Using VBA I want to copy the whole Worksheet "New Table1" into a different Workbook(Workbook2), but when I do so, the copied formula in Workbook2 changes to

`=COUNTIF('C:\Users\a.hopf\Desktop\[Workbook1.xlsx]New Table2 '!B:B;"D")`

How can I prevent the formula from referencing to the original workbook? The Formula in Workbook2 should also reference to New Table2 in Workbook2. I tried using $ to create a absolute reference, but `=COUNTIF($'New Table2'!$B:$B;"D")` doesn't work.

I know I could write the formula into Workbook2 using VBA , but I would prefer to copy it together with the worksheet from Workbook1.

Comment: Is the formula supposed to contain a comma instead of a semi-colon? I get an error with a semi-colon.

Comment: Are you copying the worksheet out of a workbook that's open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the worksheet like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyFormulasWithoutExternalLinks()

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    Set r2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets(1).UsedRange

                            'Range("G1") in r1: =COUNTIF('New Table2'!B:B/"D")

    r1.Copy r2              'Range("G1") in r2: =COUNTIF('[Book1.xlsm]New Table2'!B:B/"D")

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Set r2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheets(1).UsedRange    'reset used range in Book2


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    r2.Formula = r1.Formula 'Range("G1") in r2: =COUNTIF('New Table2'!B:B/"D")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    '(all formulas in Book2 will be invalid if 'New Table2' sheet is missing)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use INDIRECT().  For example:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'New Table2'!B:B");"D")
```